# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'?

Tags: python, string, while-loop

```
def read_grade(gradefile):

    '''
    (file,'r') --->  list of floats

    In this case it will return grade from file,   
    this fution is meant to use with given grade file'''

    line = gradefile.readline()
    print(line) 
    while line != '\n':
       line = gradefile.readline()
       print(line) 

   grades = []

   line = gradefile.readline()
   print(line)

    while line != '':
       grade = line[line.rfind(' ') + 1:]
       grades.append(float(grade))
       line = gradefile.readline()
       print(line)

    return grades

def range_grade(grades):        
    '''
    (list of int) ---> list of int

    Return a list where each index indicates how many grades were in these ranges
   '''
   grade_range = [0] *11

   for grade in grades:
      which_range = int(grade // 10)
      grade_range[which_range] = grade_range[which_range] + 1

   return grade_range


 #Main body starts


 file_path = 'C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/python/grade.txt'
 file = open(file_path,'r')

 hista_file_path ='C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/python/hista.txt'
 hista_file = open(hista_file_path,'w')


#read grades

grades = read_grade(file)

#count grade per range

range_counts = read_grade(grades)

print(range_counts)
```

Prints before main body are just for debugging, problem is while loop is not stopping even when line == '', EOF

grade.txt

```
*Grade File for python learning created by Mukul Jain on 11 May 2015

0052 77.5
0072 66
0133 100
0123 89
0402 51
0032 72
0144 22
0082 26
0024 79
0145 12
0524 60
0169 99
```

The file grade.txt ends after an \n "99" i.e. it is like 99\n

This is an question from Python tut on coursera

Any help will be grateful

Comment: The first thing is that you're calling read_grade twice, when really you want to call range_grades the second time, right? Also every time you call readline(), python will read the next line of the file. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Yeah and you know how I am feeling now, too much Embarrassed,, thanks alot for pointing out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the second column in your file as floats:

```
def read_grade(gradefile):
    next(gradefile)
    next(gradefile)
    return [float(line.split()[1]) for line in gradefile]
```

This assumes you want throw away the first two lines in the file.
You split each line at whitespace and convert all numbers in the second column to floats.

Now:

```
grades = read_grade(gradefile)
range_grade(grades)
```

returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Yeah thats another method, thanks for it but whats wrong with this one
Hey got my  answer, thanks for this alternative btw.

Comment: @borda Your methods works. But is much longer and more complicated than it needs to be.  Try to avoid using a `while` loop and searching for `’’` as EOF. Python is doing all this for you. Just looping with `for` over the lines of file is likely the most pythonic way to do it. It is not just about to make it work no matter how, but having useful answers for users too.